# Shortcut for going to previous file in PhpStorm

Tags: laravel-5, keyboard-shortcuts, phpstorm

I've installed the [Laravel 5 IDE Helper](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper) and searched the Laravel Docs for a shortcut: is it possible going to the last file I edited?

For example: I'm editing the Controller File, skipping to a view, then want to go back to the Controller file. Or even Better, would it be possible using the Laravel Plugin, going from view->controller? Any Ideas?

Comment: What Laravel IDE helper and Laravel Docs have to do with file/editor tab navigation in PhpStorm?

Comment: Sorry - forgot to mention that i'm both new to phpStorm + Laravel :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Switcher` (<kbd>Ctrl + Tab</kbd>) to switch to the most recently used tab(s) -- same idea as <kbd>Alt + Tab</kbd> in Windows.

Partially similar functionality (recently used files, even those that are currently closed):

- `View | Recent Files` (<kbd>Ctrl + E</kbd>)
- `View | Recently Changed Files` (<kbd>Ctrl + Shift + E</kbd>)

Another possible (partially related to your request) functionality: `Navigate | Back` or `Navigate | Last Edit Location`. Obviously, these actions depend on your further navigation in current view file after you came from controller -- the more places in this file you have visited/edited the more times you need to invoke these actions to go back to previous file.